# UEFI BIOS disabled second monitor

Tags: multiple-monitors, bios

I'm having a problem after I got my new monitor (LG 27QN600-B). I was not able to to get my old monitor to connect. I tried updating my BIOS and it reverted to CSM mode and both monitors worked but I need my computer to be in UEFI mode to enable secure boot which is required by window 11. What should I do?

Comment: It would help to give more information about your computer, display adapter, the monitors and their ports, and a more detailed description of the problem.

Comment: Does the second monitor work when the operating system has finished loading? What connection does each monitor use (e.g. HDMI)? Are they connected to a separate video card in the computer?

Comment: The LG monitor is connected via a HDMI cable. The other is DVI. The second monitor doesn’t work once booted into windows. Both are connected to my video card

Comment: I forgot to mention that I had two working monitors before I replaced one of them with the LG one

Comment: If you have only the LG monitor connected, does it work? What is the make and model of the video card? Sometimes they seem to need to "see" just one monitor at power-on to jog them into realising a new monitor is being used. (Also, some of the questions in the Related section on the right of this page might be useful.)